# Create a simple download link using twig

Tags: 8, theming

I want to create a simple download link on twig using Drupal8 but as easy as it can seems, I didn't find anything that was matching for me, it will always be the same file to download, it will be stock directly on the server so I don't need something that change up to parameters.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twig files take up Html markup. 
If its not something dynamic, just use the link tag.

```
<a href="/server_path/filename.jpg" download>
```

Comment: thank you that's my second day using twig and when i was looking for something similar they were creating a route etc. Worked perfectly